# Make a new design of Stack with a new function

Tags: java, linked-list, stack

I am doing some coding exercise, and I am not sure if I have met the requirement. Can someone help me to figure it out?

How would you design a stack which, in addition to push and pop, also has a function min which returns the minimum element? Push, pop and min should all operate in O(1) time.

```
public class Question {
private Node top;
private Node min;

public void push(int data) {
    Node newNode = new Node(data);
    Node newMin = new Node(data);
    if (top == null) {
        this.top = newNode;
        this.min = newMin;
    } else {
        newNode.next = this.top;
        this.top = newNode;
        if (newMin.data < this.min.data) {
            newMin.next = this.min;
            this.min = newMin;
        }
    }
}

public int pop() {
    if (top == null) {
        return -1;
    }
    int tempInt = this.top.data;
    if (this.top.data == this.min.data) {
        this.min = this.min.next;
    }
    this.top = this.top.next;
    return tempInt;
}

public int min() {
    return this.min.data;
}
public String toString(){
    return "Current top is: " + this.top.data + ", current min is: " + this.min();
}

class Node {
    Node next;
    int data;

    public Node(int data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Question tempQue = new Question();
    for(int i = 100; i > 0; i--){
        tempQue.push(i);
        System.out.println(tempQue);
    }
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 99; i++){
        tempQue.pop();
        System.out.println(tempQue);
    }
}
}
```

I have tested this code but I am not sure if the Operating time meets the requirement \$O(1)\$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's O(1) no loops or recursion that I can see.

You shouldn't have to keep 2 stacks though. You can instead a second `minNext` field in the Node. It should be null except for when it contains the minimum of all subsequent elements (or it would be the top if the min stack).

```
public void push(int data) {
    Node newNode = new Node(data);
    if (top == null) {
        this.top = newNode;
        this.min = newMin;
    } else {
        newNode.next = this.top;
        this.top = newNode;
        if (newMin.data < this.min.data) {
            newNode.nextMin = this.min;
            this.min = newNode;
        }
    }
}

public int pop() {
    if (top == null) {
        return -1;
    }
    int tempInt = this.top.data;
    if (this.top == this.min) { // check for equality of the nodes themselves
        this.min = this.top.nextMin;
    }
    this.top = this.top.next;
    return tempInt;
}
```